# Interviewer requesting on-site interview for next day

Tags: interviewing, job-change

I am currently employed full-time but am trying to change jobs.

A prospective employer has called me in for an on-site interview but asked it to be midday the next day. This, IMO, is too short notice.

I have asked it to be next week but am also wondering whether this is too far away and pushes the job away from me.

What is the best way to respond? I had assumed prospective companies should be lenient about this.

Comment: Is this a phone interview or an onsite interview? I've also edited your question slightly to clarify it, to hopefully get some more focused answers.

Comment: @enderland, the edit makes sense, thanks, and it's an on-site/face-to-face interview.

Comment: Just ask. Maybe one of the interviewer's is not available later? You have a full-time job, so they should expect this if they want to hire people with experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the common practice here? I had thought prospective companies
>   should be lenient about this.

I'm not sure there's a "common practice", but in general scheduling interviews is about convenience, and the needs of both the hiring company and the candidate(s).

Sometimes, a company wants to expand and fill a future, not too immediate, need. They may be casually interviewing candidates, and not in too much of a hurry. Waiting a week might be perfectly acceptable.

But when hiring a replacement, the hiring company often wants to fill their open position as quickly as possible. They need to see candidates, narrow them down and make a hiring decision, to start the process of bringing their team back up to size. In that case, it isn't surprising that they might want you in soon. Tomorrow, just might happen to be convenient for the people you would need to meet.

If that doesn't work for you, try to arrange a time that does, but is as soon as possible. Presumably, you picked next week as the soonest you can get there.

While waiting a week to start interviewing might be fine, it's also possible they have several other candidates who have already interviewed, and that they are nearing the end of their interviewing process. In that case, a week might be too long from their point of view.

It's also possible that the hiring company might conclude that you aren't as interested in the position as they would like, since you don't want to rearrange your schedule to see them sooner than a week.

At this point, since you have already proposed a 1 week wait, it's not worth worrying about. They will have already decided if a week is good for them or not.

Answer (score 2):

Some employers are basically in 'emergency' situations and need a body Right Now. It is unrealistic for them to expect you to drop what you're doing and show up in one working day, however it would be a good idea for you to visit with them within three days if at all possible.

The other concern is that there might be a 'bidding war' if you have alternatives on the table - the idea is to get you committed before anyone else gets hold of you.  However, the 'right now' gambit might also be an attempt to see if you're employed - if you're still living with your parents you'll show up the instant they call. In this case 'fast' isn't necessarily good.  There are good reasons to delay your visit long enough to plan around it, but a week is stretching it.

Two other notes: if the company isn't particularly clear of what they want, you may be jumping out of the frying pan into the fire.  What is left unsaid is what you'll find out after you start.  I had an employer give me a bunch of IQ tests, but they wouldn't tell me what environment they were running.  This could be evidence of significant 'technical debt' - you may find their environment is so obsolete it creaks.

If you have time to read up on company reviews, you might find they're a snakepit, or at least they're getting knocked around by ex-s. This would be another reason for a big hurry - make an offer before you have time to absorb feedback.  Caution is advised.

Comment: The last time I got an IQ test in an interview, the company turned out to be a shill for Scientology.  People got killed over the mess that followed, literally.  Google "William Rex Fowler"